# How to prevent error logging in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I'm using a httpResponseInterceptor to check for an expired session token. I'm able to detect it and end my session with a nice notification to my user, but I'm still looking for a way for the console to not output the request error:

> GET http://api.xx.xx/accounts/82 401 (Unauthorized)

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
responseError: function(rejection) {
      if(rejection.status === 401 && rejection.data.error === "Token expired"){

        //notify user of being logged out if they were logged in
        [...]

        //destroy session (will also unset cookies)
        LoginService.destroy();

      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
```

To be clear: i DO want to reject the promise, since some active processes should be cancelled. I just don't want the error message.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can 'decorate' the exception handler with angular's decorator:

```
angular.module('yourapp').config(function ($provide) {
    // catch exceptions in angular
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            var message = exception.message;
            if (message != 'YOUR ERROR TO AVOID') {
                $delegate(exception, cause); // If this does not execute - no log would be printed to console
            }
        }

    }])
});
```